# How to change Date format to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to change output date format of parameter `@DateIssued` to `"2013-12-31"` format.

Comment: Check about `SET DATEFORMAT`... Or you mean only about output format?

Comment: It is always better output the date in `date` data type instead of char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(), 126)
```

or in your case:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), @DateIssued, 126)
```

You can look into [CAST and CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

What you want:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@DateIssued,21)
```